# Show Vim relative paths with parent folders

Tags: vim, relative-path

I'm usually using GVim with multiple tabs opened, and I usually switch manually my working directory on whatever buffer I'm working on.

Each tab then gets as label the relative path of their respective files from my buffer.
However this only works when the other files are further down in folders, while other files display a full path starting from my home folder.

Is it possible to make vim display ALL paths relative to :pwd, using `..` as necessary?

Example:

```
:pwd -> /home/files/folder1

tab1label = file1
tab2label = ../folder2/file2
```

EDIT:
I actually just realized that the default behaviour of GVim is exactly the one I want, however as soon as I `:cd` to another folder the `..` go away.

Comment: Did you read `:h guitablabel` and `:h filename-modifiers`?

Comment: I did read `guitablabel`, but not `filename-modifiers`. It could be that the one I want is `:.`, but I have no idea on how to insert that into the variable. `%{:.}` doesn't work.

Comment: Try `%{expand('%:.')}`.

Comment: Works, but in the end it doesn't do what I want unfortunately. Still reports other paths from either root or home.

Comment: Even in the examples there's not one that uses `..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've coded my own solution.. since it is my first attempt at vim coding is probably not the best, but it's working correctly.

```
function RelativePathString(file)
    let filelist=split(a:file,'/')
    if len(filelist) == 0
        return "[No name]"
    endif

    let dir=getcwd()
    let dirlist=split(dir,'/')

    let finalString=""

    let i = 0
    for str in dirlist
        if str !=# filelist[i]
            break
        else
            let i += 1
        endif
    endfor

    let j=0
    let k=len(dirlist)-i
    while j < k
        let finalString .= "../"
        let j += 1
    endwhile

    let j=len(filelist)-1
    while i < j
        let finalString .= filelist[i] . "/"
        let i += 1
    endwhile
    let finalString .= filelist[i]

    return finalString
endfunction

let &guitablabel="%!RelativePathString(expand('%:p'))"
```

Comment: One issue with this solution. Sometimes when switching from another app to vim after some time, the cwd changes, and the paths displayed look like `../../../../../file.js`. The cwd gets updated after I switch to another window or tab. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the mailing list? I found two helpful answers, but maybe you will find more.

- [What abbreviates filenames in tab labels?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/sDuJUuz8YYY/MBrw7T2CDwkJ) has a `ShortGuiTabLabel()` function and a reminder for the `pathshorten()` Vim function.
- [cut off complete file path of tabnames](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/cfT6Y1sco1M/xHRcgP23UKMJ) has another custom function.

I'm not sure if these answer your question but they might help steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works almost twice as fast, comparing to Svalorzen's:

```
fu! RelativePathString(file)
    if strlen(a:file) == 0
        retu "[No Name]"
    en
    let common = getcwd()
    let result = ""
    while substitute(a:file, common, '', '') ==# a:file
        let common = fnamemodify(common, ':h')
        let result = ".." . (empty(result) ? '' : '/' . result)
    endw
    let forward = substitute(a:file, common, '', '')
    if !empty(result) && !empty(forward)
        retu result . forward
    elsei !empty(forward)
        retu forward[1:]
    en
endf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substitute(expand('%:p'), getcwd(), '..', '')
```

With

```
/home/romainl
```

as working directory, the short snippet above turns

```
/home/romainl/.vim/helpers/functions.vim
```

into

```
../.vim/helpers/functions.vim
```

Obviously, it won't be very useful when you edit a file that is outside of the working directory.